# Bootstrap popover - remove arrow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following div:

```
<span data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body">Press Me!</span>
```

with the following popup:

```
  <div id="popover-content" class="hide"> ... </div>
```

How do I remove the arrow from the popover window??

Comment: give more code that can describe your problem.

Comment: provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). so that we could understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.popover.bottom .arrow {visibility:hidden;}

Answer (score 7):

You may add CSS where you can choose the popover and then the arrow. After, you may be able to customise the arrow and hide it eventually.

```
.popover .arrow {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is that if you need to set the `template` popover option which by default is the following one:

```
'<div class="popover">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
  <div class="popover-content"></div>
</div>'
```

You could simply exclude the following `div` element:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

If you need more info you could visit the following website:

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-popovers.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm using reactstrap and this worked for me:

```
<Popover ... hideArrow={true}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here using `react-bootstrap`. Here's my `CustomTooltip` component with `arrowHidden` prop:

(note the `arrowProps` prop of the bootstrap's `Tootlip` component)

```
import React from "react";
import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Placement } from "react-bootstrap/esm/types";

const CustomTooltip = ({
  children,
  tooltipText,
  placement = "bottom",
  arrowHidden = true,
}: {
  children: JSX.Element;
  tooltipText: string;
  placement?: Placement;
  arrowHidden?: boolean;
}) => {
  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      placement={placement}
      overlay={(props) => (
        <Tooltip
          id={`tooltip-id-${tooltipText}`}
          {...props}
          arrowProps={{ style: { display: arrowHidden ? "none" : "initial" } }}
        >
          {tooltipText}
        </Tooltip>
      )}
    >
      {children}
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
};

export default CustomTooltip;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in your css.

```
.popover .popover-arrow{
    display: none;
}
```

Some people here already gave this answer but the class name changed. In bootstrap 5.0 it's now `.popover-arrow` instead of `.arrow`.